# Using a query on a joined table instead of actual table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query now which works great for finding player info including their rank:

```
SELECT  t1.pid, 
        t1.type, 
        t1.pspeed, 
        t1.distance, 
        t1.maxspeed, 
        t1.prestrafe, 
        t1.strafes, 
        t1.sync, 
        t1.wpn, 
        1+SUM(t2.pid IS NOT NULL) as rank 
FROM    records t1 
        LEFT JOIN records t2
            ON  t1.type = t2.type 
                AND t1.pspeed = t2.pspeed 
                AND t1.distance < t2.distance
WHERE   t1.pid = "'.$pid.'" 
        AND t1.type IN ("type1","type2","type3")
GROUP   BY t1.type, t1.pspeed
```

The problem now is that I wish to use an `authid` instead of a `pid` as my variable. I can do an easy join on the `records` table along with a `player` table that has an `id` equal to the `pid` in the `records` table as well as the `authid` I wish to search by:

```
SELECT * FROM records JOIN players ON records.pid=players.id
```

I wish to use this second query in place of the `FROM records` portion of the first query but I've confused myself in my attempts via the many aliases used.

Here's a pitiful example of an attempt:

```
SELECT  t1.pid, 
        t1.type, 
        t1.pspeed, 
        t1.distance,
        t1.maxspeed, 
        t1.prestrafe, 
        t1.strafes, 
        t1.sync, 
        t1.wpn, 
        1+SUM(t2.pid IS NOT NULL) as rank
FROM    (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    records 
                    JOIN players ON records.pid=players.id
        ) t3 t1
        LEFT JOIN records t2
            ON  t1.type = t2.type 
                AND t1.pspeed = t2.pspeed 
                AND t1.distance < t2.distance
WHERE   t1.authid = "'.$authid.'" 
        AND t1.type IN ("type1","type2","type3")
GROUP   BY t1.type, t1.pspeed
```

Anyone able to whip me into shape please feel free to do so. I'm awful at SQL still.

Comment: Something seems wrong with this line: `(SELECT * FROM records JOIN players ON records.pid=players.id) t3 t1`

Comment: Post the error message you are receiving.

Comment: This scares me: `WHERE   t1.pid = "'.$pid.'" `. It says you're building queries that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Join looks pretty close. However you gave your subquery two aliases. Try just one

```
SELECT t1.pid, t1.type, t1.pspeed, t1.distance, t1.maxspeed, t1.prestrafe, t1.strafes, t1.sync, t1.wpn, 1+SUM(t2.pid IS NOT NULL) as rank
FROM
(
      SELECT players.*, rec.pid, rec.type, rec.pspeed, rec.distance, rec.maxspeed, 
      rec.prestrafe, rec.strafes, rec.sync, rec.wpn 
      FROM records AS rec JOIN players ON rec.pid = players.id  ) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN records t2
ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.pspeed = t2.pspeed AND t1.distance < t2.distance
WHERE t1.authid = "'.$authid.'" AND 
t1.type IN ("type1","type2","type3")
GROUP BY t1.type, t1.pspeed
```

Also, naming your columns in your subquery should eliminate the duplicate column error.

Comment: I get a "duplicate column name `id`" error. That's why I tried two aliases.

Comment: does _records_ have a column of ID? There are two ID columns coming through and the query engine cannot discern which is which. You must alias one of them, or remove it from the select column list.